# Asp.net mvc3 file Uploader from server side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net mvc3 with file Uploader Ctrl.

How to set Default Open file Dialog box path to Server folder?

```
<input type="file" runat="server"  name="@item.Id" id="fu_@item.Id" value="@Html.Encode(item.FileName)" title="@item.FileName" disabled="disabled"  style="width: 700px;" />
```

runat="server" Will open server File open Dialog box?

and how to set Default Path in this?

is there any other why then plz. let know..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First things first in ASP.NET MVC you no longer should employ the `runat="server"` attribute on any of your DOM elements in the markup. As far as your question about setting default folders to the Open File dialog is concerned, for security reasons, this is not possible to be done on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this, the path that it opens up at is entirely up to the users browser, I don't think you can influence this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it...

You can manipulate the default path of the FileUpload control in MVC3...

in your .cshtml file you can use this kind of approach or similar...

```
using (Begin.Form("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { new enctype="multipart/form-data", @id="Upload", path="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.Appsettings[@"DialogDefaultPath] }))
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.'YourPropertyToGetPath', new { @type="file", @id="fileUpload })
}
```

**OPTIONAL SINCE I USE THE APPSETTINGS. YOU CAN HARDCODE IT IF YOU WANT**

in your Web.Config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DialogDefaultPath" value="**DESIRED PATH**"/>
</appSettings>
```